# Movie with "time loop" where historic figures are summoned through a mirror

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm looking for a (dark?) fantasy/adventure movie with a male protagonist. The setting is Jules Verne like I guess. There is only one scene I can vaguely remember:

At one point the protagonist comes to some kind of mansion and is asked if he wants to stay for the night. He sits at the dinner table with his host. He asks the host when he can leave and the host replies that the horses will be ready the next day. He then drinks from the wine and kind of naps away. This sequence repeats a couple of times, each time the protagonist can only vaguely remember that he has been at the dinner table before. His host wants to keep him at the mansion for some reason.

After a few repetitions the protagonist notices that there is dried blood at the tips of his fingers. At one point he does not drink the wine and "stays awake" to see what his host does during the night.

It turns out the host is summoning figures from history (Hannibal or such) through some kind of magic mirror (?) and he needs the blood to do that.

The protagonist escapes by summoning so many people through the mirror that it gets over the head of his host and he allows him to leave.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: [**Identify-This-X Questions**](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I agree that more background is needed. Still, if it's an *extremely* detailed plot description, that's good too. Possible answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like a scene from Gulliver's visit in Laputa in the 1996 [Gulliver's Travels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulliver%27s_Travels_(miniseries)) miniseries.

> After leaving the Academy, [Gulliver] encounters a magician (Omar Sharif) in Glubbdubdrib and stays at his house with the promise of being taken to a port to go to England. While the days pass, **Gulliver wonders when will this be as the magician only says his servants are looking for two horses that escaped and that they'll "go tomorrow." Gulliver later discovers the magician is drugging him and using his blood to summon the ghosts of great figures such as Alexander the Great (Ian Dunn) and Julius Caesar. Gulliver later summons more spirits by his own will.** After summoning many spirits, he abandons the place realizing everything's an illusion when he goes through two standing guardians.

IIRC he summoned them through some magic mirror. Ted Danson played the lead. See if the trailer jogs your memory:

Comment: That's it! Awesome! And I thought the main character was played by Christopher Lambert ... well he looks somewhat like him.